# Does Katalon support opening webUI and mobile driver in same script

Tags: katalon-studio

We want to execute a automation test case wherein first operations will happen on WebUI and then it will switch to Mobile execution. The process will be done sequentially. I want to write all script in one testcase itself. First script will execute on Chrome browser then in connected mobile device.I am looking for someone who has achieved this in katalon. I need a solution other than test suite collection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using profiles in katalon :
https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/execution-profile-v54.html

Please also remeber that this is not only **profiles**but also enviroment (chrome or mobile). You can use this Execution window as example what eviroment i am talking about.
[image: Enviroment select]